# SKScene texture to SceneKit problem transparency

Tags: textures, scenekit, arkit, skscene

I'm using SKScene to create a texture with dynamic text content. Everything works but I've got a strange problem when display texture.
When I move camera, sometimes texture become transparent and I can see through my 3D model. I try many things but I can't find a solution.

Here is two images. First one is OK but the second show the problem, I can see through 3D model. Texture acts as a mask.

[image: SceneKit render OK]

[image: SceneKit render problem]

Someone has already encountered this problem ?
Do you have an idea on how to correct this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some complementary tests, I found the problem. It comes from my 3D model. I used a 3D software to clean mesh and normals and after that, everything works fine !